# "undefined" when trying to improve a suggested edit

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, popups, improve-edit

While improving a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/210490), the suggestion was apparently improved by someone else, and I was barred from making my changes (this is fine and expected). I left the window as-is, but tried to improve further and submit again, since the message states my edit must be more substantive.

Upon resubmitting, the pop-up below was displayed. Any attempts to try again resulted in the same.

> [image: Error example]

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Just seen it too, so bug is still there.